# A colorful metapuzzle (of a sort)

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, grid-deduction

[image]

*edit: realized two puzzles ended up being variants. Replaced subpuzzle 5 completely, and swapped subpuzzle 2 to the original version. Either version has the same solution.*

*edit 2: my apologies. this was originally meant for a test solve, and I pushed it live far too early it seems. Added a couple more givens to puzzles 2 and 6 to bring their difficulty more in line with the rest of the subgrids. Also, had to replace the Minesweeper because I am made of fail.*

Hint:

> [image]

Comment: It looks to me like the second and fifth puzzles are variants, and I haven't identified the eighth yet...

Comment: The eighth looks similar to rot13(uggcf://ybtvpchmmyr.wxyngrk.qr/fgnefnaqneebjf) but not sure what the black circle is. perhaps an rot13(nyernql cynprq fgne)?

Comment: Update: solved all puzzles except second, fifth, and sixth so far. (The sixth just because I'm bad at that genre; the other two seem underconstrained, but may also just be me being bad.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each of these grids is

> a common logic puzzle genre. These genres are, in order:
>
>  Hidato; Str8ts; Battleships; Sudoku
>  Kakurasu; Skyscrapers; Minesweeper; Stars and Arrows
>  Tapa; Light and Shadow; Nurikabe; Fillomino

Solutions are below:

> [image]

(Puzzles 2, 5, 6, and 7 were solved by Reinier.)

For the next step:

> Each of the grids is a different color. (The grids on the right look black, but they are very dark shades of red, green, and blue.)
>
>  These colors are hexadecimal `88`, `44`, `22`, and `11` in one of the channels, and 0 in the other two.
>
>  The text says "get to the heart of everything... all that is left is a single color". In all of the grids, the center cell is unclued; we can use the top right guide to convert the solutions to each puzzle to "shaded" or "unshaded", and then "add" the shaded colors together.
>
>  `#000000 + #440000 + #220000 + #000000`
>  `+ #000000 + #000000 + #002200 + #001100`
>  `+ #000011 + #000044 + #000022 + #000011`
>  `... = 663399`
>
>  This is a color that has the name "rebeccapurple" in the CSS color list; its "deeper meaning" is that it was named after Rebecca Meyer, who was a daughter of web designer Eric Meyer and who passed away at a young age due to a brain tumor.

Comment: That is not the answer, but your logic seems to make some form of sense...

Comment: Your last row is a bit off... I'm assuming you mean #000088 + #000000 + #000000 + #000001

Answer (score 5):

Continuing from Deusovi's work, here are the solutions to the remaining subpuzzles
(the second from the first row, and the first, second and third from the second row. The rest is copied from Deusovi)

> [image]

Comment: Now you just need to make the squares with even numbers black and....uh...figure out what to do next. :)